# Create a user who can't delete data in influxdb?

Tags: influxdb

Is it possible to create a non-admin user who can't delete data in influxdb?

I would like to create a user who can read/write (query/insert) data but not delete what has already been inserted.

According to what I can see in the [official docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.1/query_language/authentication_and_authorization/#non-admin-users), I don't think I can. Is that correct? Or is there a sneaky workaround?

> ***Non-admin users***
>
> Non-admin users can have one of the following three privileges per database:
>   * `READ`
>   ◦ `WRITE`
>   ◦ `ALL` (both `READ` and `WRITE` access)
>
> `READ`, `WRITE`, and `ALL` privileges are controlled per user per database. A new non-admin user has no access to any database until they are specifically [granted privileges to a database](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.1/query_language/authentication_and_authorization/#grant-read-write-or-all-database-privileges-to-an-existing-user) by an admin user.

> **`GRANT` `READ`, `WRITE` or `ALL` database privileges to an existing user**:
>
> ```
> GRANT [READ,WRITE,ALL] ON <database_name> TO <username>
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,
Deleting is a *write* operation. *Write* privilege allows you to make changes which can be adding, overwriting, or deleting things. Even if deleting was somehow restricted, if you can insert data then you can always overwrite existing data which allows you to destroy any actual data, essentially "deleting" it.

EDIT: as pointed out in the comment below, this applies for community edition of influxdb. Indeed the Enterprise edition supports more refined roles, and supports what the OP asked for, namely `DROP_DATA` role. Read more here https://docs.influxdata.com/chronograf/v1.7/administration/managing-influxdb-users/#dropdata and here https://docs.influxdata.com/enterprise_influxdb/v1.7/guides/fine-grained-authorization/

Comment: Thx. If you edit your answer to specify that this is for the community edition and that only the enterprise edition supports advanced permission settings, I'll accept the answer.